# Вывод списка подкатегорий учитывая выбранного родителя

Tags: php

Всем привет! Помогите найти решение. Есть продукты `product`. У продуктов есть связь с таблицами отвечающие за категорию `category` и подкатегорию `category_sub`. При создании нового продукта `product` и выборе продукта, категории и подкатегории все работает. Сначала я выбираю список category потом ajax запрос подгружает во второй выпадающий список подкатегории `category_sub`. Проблема в странице редактирования продукта `product`. Я могу отобразить выпадающий список текущей категории, но не получается отобразить список текущей подкатегории, чтобы список подкатегории выводил список учитывая какая родительская категория.

Таблица **product**

| prod_id | product_name | product_cat | product_subcat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Булочка с изюмом | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | Батон нарезной | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | Лего набор | 2 | 3 |

Таблица **category**

| cat_id | cat_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Еда |
| 2 | Игрушки |

Таблица **category_sub**

| subcat_id | subcat_name | subcat_rod |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Хлеб | 1 |
| 2 | Булочки | 1 |
| 3 | Конструкторы | 2 |
| 4 | Пончик | 1 |

К примеру если я редактирую **prod_id №1** (Булочка с изюмом )

то на странице редактирования мне нужно в первом выпадающем списке отобразить помеченную текущую категорию
`<option selected>Еда</option>` и при раскрытии списка показать остальные категории
а во втором выпадающем списке мне нужно отобразить текущую подкатегорию продукта `<option selected>Булочки</option>` и вывести список всех подкатегорий текущей категории `Еда`

Первый выпадающий список (категории)

(тут все норм)

```
<div class="mb-3">
                  <div class="form-label">Категория</div>
                  <select class="form-select" id="category_filter" name="cat_id">
                    <?php
                    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM category");
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $categories = $stmt->fetchAll();
                    foreach($categories as $category) {

                      if ($sercat == $category["id"]):
                        echo '<option selected name="'.$category['cat_id'].'" value="'.$category['cat_id'].'">'.$category['cat_name'].'</option>';

                      else:
                        echo '<option name="'.$category['cat_id'].'" value="'.$category['cat_id'].'">'.$category['cat_name'].'</option>';

                  endif;
                    }
                    ?>
                  </select>
                </div>
```

**Второй выпадающий список (подкатегории) <- вот тут как раз проблема**

```
<div class="mb-3">
                  <div class="form-label">Подкатегория</div>
                  <select class="form-select" id="subcat" name="subcat">
                      <?php
                      $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM category_sub");
                      $stmt->execute();
                      $categories = $stmt->fetchAll();
                      foreach($categories as $category) {

                        if ($sersubcat == $category["subcat_id"]):
                          echo '<option selected name="'.$category['subcat_id'].'" value="'.$category['subcat_id'].'">'.$category['subcat_name'].'</option>';

                        else:
                          echo '<option name="'.$category['subcat_id'].'" value="'.$category['subcat_id'].'">'.$category['subcat_name'].'</option>';

                    endif;
                      }
                      ?>
                  </select>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Не надо столько таблиц в базе. Запросы к ней будут дольше, нагрузка выше.
Сделай одну таблицу в которой одна строка - это самая низжая из категорий.

### Т.е вот так:
Таблица category:
id cat_name subcat_name

1 - Булочки - Булочка с изюмом
2 - Булочки - Булочка с творогом
3 - Хлеб - Батон
4 - Хлеб - Ржаной

И когда надо будет вывести сначала главные категории:
SELECT DISTINCT cat_name FROM category

И потом в этом foreach чтобы вывести подкатегории:
SELECT * FROM category WHERE cat_name = '{$cat_name}'